# Centos7 installation of WireGuard, the client only sends traffic but not receives it

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

My purpose is simple, A is the server, B is the phone, B can forward all the traffic to A and then use A to access the Internet
A has a separate public IP address
Here is my server configuration and cell phone configuration file

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = $(cat servie_privatekey)
Address = 10.1.1.1/24
SaveConfig = true


PostUp  = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

ListenPort = 50814
DNS = 223.5.5.5
MTU = 1420

[Peer]
#手机
PublicKey =  $(cat phone_publickey)
AllowedIPs = 10.1.1.2/32
```

Mobile Phone Profiles

```
[Interface]
  PrivateKey = $(cat phone_privatekey)
  Address = 10.1.1.2/24
  DNS = 223.5.5.5
  MTU = 1420

[Peer]
  PublicKey = $(cat servie_publickey)
  #Endpoint = wowxql.top:50814
  Endpoint = 96.45.163.157:50814
  AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
  PersistentKeepalive = 25 " > phone.conf
```

IP forwarding is turned on

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The problem is that after the cell phone connects, it only sends and does not receive, the server can see the connection information by entering the command "WG", and the IP address of the cell phone, but there is no way for the cell phone to access any network

I am surprised that the same configuration can be achieved on another system

Comment: 1) Try lowering the `MTU` on both sides of the connection, like to `1280`. 2) Perhaps you have some other firewall rules on the server that are ordered before the `FORWARD` iptables rule from your WireGuard config? (run `sudo iptables-save` and `sudo nft list ruleset` to check)

Comment: I have a similar problem. The client connects to the server, it shows a request at my pi-hole log, but the website fails to load. Did you manage to solve it?